# При попытки удалить из БД id появляется ошибка database is locked

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot, sqlite3

```
def post_sql_query(sql_query):
    with sqlite3.connect('users.db') as connection:
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        try:
            cursor.execute(sql_query)
        except Error:
            print(Error)
        result = cursor.fetchall()
        return result

@bot.message_handler(commands=['test'])
def test(message):
    if (message.from_user.id == my_id):
        try:
                
            with sqlite3.connect("users.db") as con:
                c = con.cursor()
                for i in c.execute("SELECT id FROM login_id"):
                    j = str(i)[1:-2]
                    teste = message.text
                    bot.send_message(int(j), teste)
                            
        except telebot.apihelper.ApiException:
            users_id = message.chat.id
            post_sql_query(f'DELETE FROM login_id WHERE id = {users_id};')
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'Нет доступа к данной команде')
```

database is locked

Answer (score 0):

Это скорее всего связано с тем, что какой-то процесс работает с твоей базой данных. Попробуй найти его и кильнуть.

Пара решений на англоязычном форуме: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151026/how-do-i-unlock-a-sqlite-database

Comment: Нет ни одного процесса,работающего с БД. Но ошибка осталась